# блок изменяющийся на textarea при нажатии

Tags: html, html5

Есть тег или атрибут для div но не могу его найти. При нажатии на div он изменялся на textarea и в нем можно было изменять содержымое блока. Это не скрипт php или js и даже не css это точно html

Comment: `<div contenteditable="true">тестовый текст</div>` http://htmlbook.ru/html/attr/contenteditable

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спасибо, оно. а как оно используеться в php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не все так просто, как может показаться на первый взгляд. При наличии аттрибута `contenteditable` div ни в коем разе не превращается в textarea при редактировании и его содержимое не отправляется на сервер при сабмите формы.

Но, к счастью, у `<div contenteditable>` появляются события, свойственные полям ввода. Мы можем использовать, к примеру, `blur` (грубо говоря - потеря фокуса).

Создаем на странице скрытый `textarea`, вешаем на `<div contenteditable>` слушатель события `blur`, в котором копируем содержимое `div` в скрытый `textarea`.

Упрощенный код примерно такой:

```
<textarea id="textarea" name="description" style="display:none"></textarea> 
<div id="div" class="textarea" contenteditable="">редактируемый текст</div>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#div").on('blur', function(){
            $("#textarea").val($(this).text());
        });
    })
</script>
```

Если же вы осуществляете полностью ручную отправку формы на сервер, то есть собираете все значения из инпутов и текстовых полей в массив, то ничто, описанное выше, вам не потребуется. Не нужны никакие скрытые `textarea`. Достаточно просто достать `$("#div").text()` и добавить его к отправляемым данным.